# Mesh not parenting to rig

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, objects, parent

I did an armature myself and tried to get it to move in sync with the mesh but it didn't work. I used rigfy, it didn't still work. I checked up  youtube and saw the concept of merging by distance before parenting, whenever I did that, I get the pop-up,"Change bone layers". I got my Mesh from Blender Assets Library. Please, what am I not doing well?

[image]

Comment: The mesh is supposed to move with the bones of the armature when you're in Pose mode, not the other way round. Please share your Blend file here. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it and then edit your question and paste the link into it.

Comment: All the attempts I've been making to move the mesh with the bones in pose mode didn't work. I have shared the file but I wonder why it's taking time to upload.

Comment: The character is a collection instance for the moment, to make it a single object press Ctral A > *Make Instances Real*, then parent *With Automatic Weights*. Now the rig doesn't seem to control the metarig but I don't know Rigify.

Comment: @moonboots, the mesh now move with the rig but not with the skeleton. Please can you help explain what "Make Instances Real" did to the Mesh?

Comment: Your object was an Collection Instance, a kind of avatar of the original object, you needed to make it real. As for the armature, I can't help because I don't know how you link the metarig to the rig, hopefully someone will tell

Comment: Oh I appreciate it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The character is a collection instance for the moment, which means it's a kind of avatar of the original object, not the real object, so you can't parent it to the armature. To make it a single object press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Make Instances Real*, then parent *With Automatic Weights*. Now the rig doesn't seem to control the metarig but I don't know Rigify.